# Rails 3.2.8, heroku: uninitialized constant Less::Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am seeing this error in a delayed job on heroku and it makes no sense to me:

```
{uninitialized constant Less::Engine
  (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/share_and_earn_recommendation_email.css.less)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/css.rb:60:in `prepare'
...
```

Why no sense? Because `css.rb` looks like this:

```ruby
def prepare
  if ::Less.const_defined? :Engine
    @engine = ::Less::Engine.new(data) # line 60
  else
  ...
```

Which means it is impossible to hit line 60 if `Less::Engine` is undefined. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Even better demonstration from heroku console:

```
irb(main):008:0> ::Less.const_defined? :Engine 
=> true
irb(main):009:0> ::Less::Engine
NameError: uninitialized constant Less::Engine
```

**EDIT 2**

It gets more interesting:

```
irb(main):011:0> ::Less.const_defined? :Engine, false 
=> false
```

The difference is that the latter does not search ancestors. But there are no ancestors, so it should not make a difference:

```
irb(main):012:0> ::Less.ancestors
=> [Less]
```

Comment: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/51795 Does that help? It suggests using defined?(Less::Engine) instead.

Comment: @JoePym not really. That thread is about `const_defined?` not seeing a defined constant. In my case it is the opposite: const is missing, but `const_defined?` is not convinced.

Comment: Just a thought: about the same time this started happening, heroku upgraded ruby https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/189?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter Although locally, with that ruby version, there is no problem

Answer (score 1):

If you just recently upgraded your rails version within the 3.2.x stack you will find that less is "present" in earlier versions like 3.2.2 and absent in later versions like 3.2.9.

I haven't fully investigated the issue, but I noticed when I went to upgrade from 3.2.2 to 3.2.9, I got some "less" issues.

Cheers

Comment: Updated question title with full version info (3.2.8). Sorry for being lame in the first place!

Comment: Also, this is not a `less` issue. `less` truly does not have `Less::Engine` defined these days. `tilt` has that check to comply with earlier versions of `less` (which is not my case)